# How to join two tables without empty column being filled from the other record?

Tags: laravel

How can I join two tables to have one record that has empty values on a specific column and the other record has its values?

The output should be like this

[image]

What is happening is that the B.column3 of the second record is being filled by the value of the first record of the same column.

I tried this code and I can't make it the correct way.

```
$orders = self::leftJoin('customer_information', function ($join) {
                $join->on('customer_information.id', '=', 'orders.customer_id')
                ->orWhere('orders.customer_id', '=', null);
            })->get();
```

How can I attain that?

order table has 
- customer_id
- order_id
- total_amount

customer_information has
- id
- name
- address

I want to get all the records from joined tables with or without customer_id.

PS :

1. self ==> orders
2. The customer_id in the orders table sometimes has null values so I cannot make a relationship with customer_information table

I am making this in the Order model.

Comment: if the order has no customer_id, just show the orders and join all empty fields of customer_information?

Comment: @TsaiKoga is it possible with only one query?

Comment: `$orders = self::leftJoin('customer_information', 'customer_information.id', '=', 'orders.customer_id')->get()`?

Comment: This works! Omg. I think I need to sleep for now. I am making things so complicated. Thanks a lot. Cheers! You may want to put this on the answer portion so that I can mark this as correct one.

Comment: you are welcome, I add it to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`leftjoin` will get all `orders` with the `customer_informations` or without `customer_information`:

```php
$orders = self::leftJoin('customer_information', 'customer_information.id', '=', 'orders.customer_id')->get()
```